# how to play video on visibitity

Tags: javascript, video

I have some videos stored in mysql database, i have fetch them to my webpage and i am trying to play the videos on visibity, i have been trying for so long now to make this videos play but only one from them keep playing , here is my code

```
 <div style="width:100%; background-color:black; margin-top:10px;">
  
  <?php
  
$m31= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `video`   " );
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m31)){        
    $vid = $row['vid'];
    $id = $row['id'];

?>

 <video id="myvideo"  style="width:100%; height:400px;"  controls   />
 <source  style="width:100%; height:400px;" src="video/<?php echo $vid ; ?>"  />
 </video>
 
     <?php } ?>
</div>

<script>
let options = {
    root:  null,
    rootmargin:'0px',
    threshold:1.0
};
    let myback = (entries, observer)=>{
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.target.id == 'myvideo'){
            if(entry.isIntersecting){
            entry.target.play();    
            }else{
            entry.target.pause();   
            }
        }
    });
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(myback, options);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#myvideo'));
```

i tryed something like this but i am getting undifined id

```
 <video id="myvideo<?php echo $id ?>"  style="width:100%; height:400px;"  controls   />
 <source  style="width:100%; height:400px;" src="video/<?php echo $vid ; ?>"  />
 </video>
 
     <?php } ?>
</div>

<script>
let options = {
    root:  null,
    rootmargin:'0px',
    threshold:1.0
};
    let myback = (entries, observer)=>{
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.target.id == 'myvideo'+id){
            if(entry.isIntersecting){
            entry.target.play();    
            }else{
            entry.target.pause();   
            }
        }
    });
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(myback, options);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#myvideo'+id));
</script>
```

Comment: `i am getting undifined id`...yes, unsurprisingly. There's nowhere in your Javascript code that you define `id` or give it a value. Where did you expect it to magically appear from?

Comment: please that is why need help what can i do to archieve it?

Comment: You're going to need to use a PHP loop to inject the necessary IDs into Javascript and generate one intersectionobserver for every video tag.